# Constructing a line that passes through $P$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

I have recently read a book by Heisuke Hironaka. However, the book is not available on English. The book was basically a biography on his life. Heisuke Hironaka says that his high school teacher had given him a problem only he had managed to solve.

"Construct a line that passes through $P$ that meets lines $AB$,$AC$, on points $K$, $M$ so that $BK=CM$."

So far, I have found out that if the perpendicular bisecor of $BC$ and the external angle bisector of $A$ met on the point $L$, for the condition $BK=CM$ to be satisfied, $LK=LM$. Also, if the line that passed through $P$ met the external angle bisector of $A$ on the point $T$, the angle $LTP$ is equal to the angle $LKA$. However, I was able to progress no further from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain how T is located in more detail.

Comment: I started work on your problem using analytic geometry. I ended up with the answer as the solution(s) to a moderately complicated quadratic equation, and the particular equation depends on several cases depending on some "betweenness" of your given points. I confirmed by other means that there may be no, one, or two answers. Constructing the answer(s) is possible but not easy. I don't have the motivation to get to the final answer. I may give my partial answer later if no one else gives you a good answer.

Comment: @Mick I`m not exactly sure how I should phrase it. I would appreciate it if you helped me. If the line that we are supposed to construct through P meets the external angle bisector of the the angle A in the triangle ABC, that point is T.

Comment: @RoryDaulton The hint given next to problem seemed to indicate that it was likely that the man had managed to Euclidean Geometry solution.

Comment: the problem is interesting. Will give it a try. Your finding about T is, after tested via Geogebra, correct.

Comment: @Mick Would you mind telling me how to add a image to this question?

Comment: If you have earned enough credits (100 as far as I can remember), then you will have a 'new' the edit menu, the 6th icon of it is a picture sign. It is for you to upload a picture (in *.png format). Otherwise, you have to load a picture in some other hosting sites. They will be given a link for your uploaded picture. Include that link in your post. For your case I will upload mine iniital sketch for your reference.

Comment: I tried but not very successful and have to give up. Below is my finding an a clarification of the point T.

Answer (score 1):

I will present a construction in two steps. There are a number of exceptional cases to be considered, but they should be ignored on first reading.

We will assume $A, B, C$ are not aligned. (Otherwise, the only solution is to let $K = M$ be the midpoint of $BC$.)

First note that there are two rotations $\rho$ which carry line $AB$ to line $AC$ and which carry $B$ to $C$. For each point $K$ of line $AB$, the corresponding point $M = \rho(K)$ satisfies $CM = BK$. Therefore the only problem is how to select $K$ so that $P$, $K$ and $M$ are aligned. In fact, all solutions are obtained this way for one of the two rotations $\rho$.

The first step in the construction is to find the centre $F$ of one of the rotations. This can be done by letting $D = \rho(A)$ be either of the two points on $AC$ satisfying $CD = BA$, and taking $F$ to be the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of segments $BC$ and $AD$, since $FB = FC, FA=FD$. (If $D = A$, let $F = A$.) Thus $\rho$ is the rotation with centre $F$ carrying $B$ to $C$.

Now for any point $K$ on $AB$ and $M = \rho(K)$ on $AC$, let $I$ be the midpoint of $KM$. As $K$ varies, it is not hard to see that the locus of $I$ is a line $a$. The line $a$ can easily be constructed by selecting two arbitrary points $K_1$ and $K_2$ on $AB$ and drawing the corresponding line $I_1 I_2$. (For example, if $K_1 = B, M_1 = C, K_2 = A, M_2 = D$, then the points $I_1$ and $I_2$ have already been constructed!) Conversely, if the midpoint $I$ of $KM$ is given, then the points $K$ and $M$ can be obtained as the intersections with $AB$ and $AC$ of the line through $I$ perpendicular to $FI$, since $I$ is the midpoint of a chord $KM$ in a circle centred at $F$. (An exceptional case occurs when $F = A = I$; in that case, $K = M = A$. There will be further exceptional cases where the chord coincides with $AB$ or $AC$; but at least one of the points $K$, $M$ can always be obtained as an intersection, and then the other as the reflection of the first with respect to $I$.)

If we let $I$ be any point on line $a$, then the corresponding points $K$ and $M$ answer the question if and only if $P$ belongs to line $KIM$. This is equivalent to $\angle FIP$ being a right angle, hence to $I$ belonging to the circle with diameter $FP$.

Therefore the last step in the construction is to take any point of intersection $I$ of line $a$ with the circle with diameter $FP$. Then $PI$ is the required line. (If, exceptionally, $P = I$, then any line through $P$ will do.)

**In summary** (general case)

- Choose $D$ on $AC$ so that $CD = BA$.
- Construct the perpendicular bisectors $l_1$ and $l_2$ of segments $BC$ and $AD$. Let $F$ be their intersection.
- Let $I_1$, $I_2$ be the midpoints of segments $BC$ and $AD$.
- Let $I$ be a point of intersection of line $I_1I_2$ with the circle with diameter $FP$.
- $PI$ is the required line.

Comment: Hmm..If this is the solution is true (I have not verified it yet) I wonder how Heisuke Hironaka managed to come up with it. In his book, he mentioned that this problem was in his finals(or some other test at school) which means that he must have solved it very quickly. However, the man is a genius, after all, so I guess I should not be very surprised.

Comment: Would you mind including a picture?

Comment: @CLMNT Well, yes, his being a genius is part of it, since as you say, he was the only one to solve the problem quickly enough. But it's hard for us to understand how much more geometry students learned in school then  than they do now. Also, I doubt a student would have been expected to discuss the special cases on a test.

Comment: @ChadShin I'm not good with that kind of software.

Comment: Really, there are only two main ideas in this solution. First, identify the two rotations that take a point $K$ to a correctly positioned $M$ (ignoring alignment with $P$). Second, construct the midpoint $I$ of $KM$, instead of constructing $K$ and $M$ directly. Interestingly, I believe the envelope of all the lines $KM$ as $K$ varies is a parabola with focus at $F$. However, this fact wasn't needed in the solution.

Comment: Therefore the problem is, given a parabola with focus $F$ and tangent to both $AB$ and $AC$, how to construct a tangent to the parabola passing through $P$. There will be $0$, $1$ or $2$ solutions according to whether $P$ is inside, on, or outside the parabola. This is just for one choice of $F$. In fact, the two foci $F_1$ and $F_2$ can be obtained as the intersection of the perpendicular bisector of segment $BC$ with the two bisectors of lines $AB$ and $AC$. Therefore the two parabolas are located in (and tangent to) supplementary angles determined by lines $AB$ and $AC$. Other than in...

Comment: ...degenerate or special cases, these parabolas have no interior or boundary points in common, since they are located within the two supplementary angles. Thus in most cases, there will be $2$, $3$ or $4$ solutions to the problem, depending on how $P$ is situated with respect to the parabolas. There could be special cases if one of the parabolas was degenerate ($F = A$), if the two parabolas touched the common side of the angles containing them at the same point, or if $P$ was located on a *common* tangent to both parabolas.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a solution. I am just sharing my finding.

[image]

1) The problem would be extremely difficult when P is just a random given point on the plane.

1.1) It is pointless to assume that ABC is isosceles with AB = AC. This is because h, the external angle bisector of angle A, is then the required line.

1.2) Then, we can assume that P is not on h but PKM will cut h at some point P’. That is, P’KM is our target line instead (which of course is a bit easier).

Following your logic, we can

(i) construct line k, the perpendicular bisector of BC; and let it cut BA extended at X;

(ii) if h cuts k at L, let circle $\pi$ [center $= L$ & radius $= LX$] cut $AB$ and $AC$ at $K_1$ and $M_1$ respectively.

$TK_1M_1$ is the required line for a special case solution only. $P’ (= T$ this time) lying on h and the line cuts the circle $\pi $ at $K_1$ and $M_1$). This can be proved by considering congruent triangles $K_1BL$ and $M_1CL$ as mentioned.

Note that $TXLK_1$ forms a cyclic quadrilateral for this special case only. Other points like P’ does not have this property.

The general case is when $P’$ is not on the circle $\pi $. Again by considering congruent triangles, we know that the required $K$ and $M$ will both lie on one of the dotted concentric circles (center $= L$) whose radius is not known because of insufficient information on $P$.