# Constructing a line through $P$ that meets $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AC}$ in points $D$ and $E$ such that $\overline{DB}\cong\overline{EC}$

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction, axiomatic-geometry

Geometry problem in Hironaka Heisuke's book. (I don't think this book is translated into English.) I saw this beautiful problem which the author said he solved it in high school:

[image]

> $P$ is a point outside of $\triangle ABC$, $\ell$ is a line crossing $P$ and splits $\triangle ABC$ into $\triangle ADE$ and $\square DEBC$.
>
> Construct $\ell$ which makes $\overline{DB} \cong\overline{EC}$.

I have tried making $\triangle ABC$ an isosceles triangle, which makes this problem very easy.
(Make $\overline{BC} \parallel \overline{PE}$.)

But if $\triangle ABC$ becomes a normal triangle like in the picture, all I can guess is that
$\overline{PE}$ has to be a bit diagonal.

I disagree with this question being closed.
I saw a similar question from the link ([Constructing a line that passes through $P$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613984/constructing-a-line-that-passes-through-p)).

But, I have a more detailed explanation with a picture.

Second, the solution to the question didn't contain an explanation with pictures, so I wanted more detailed answers. (the second answer includes a picture but he said it is not a solution)

Lastly, I added my try of solving different from the original question.

Comment: Reposting a question is not the appropriate way to circumvent closure. Rather, you should edit the original to improve its quality in hopes of attracting re-open votes. Closing-and-reposting could be considered a violation of community standards; see, for instance, the Meta.SE post ["Reposting a closed or held question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302687/reposting-a-closed-or-held-question).

Comment: @Blue The original is probably closed as a duplicate and subsequently deleted, like this one is going to be too.  It was not because of a "lack of explanation" as OP thought.

Comment: @Blue I saw the original question, but I think I presented more detailed information including a picture(I think picture is main part in this kind of question.), and I presented my try of solving different from the original question. Although the question is the same, can this be considered as asking a different question?